# Can long term capital loss be claimed in India when shares are moved to escrow account for dissolution

Tags: income-tax, india, capital-gains-tax, capital-loss

I am an Indian resident taxpayer.  I had shares of Yahoo which were traded as Altaba Inc. (AABA),  held for more than 4yrs in a US demat account.  The company has filed for dissolution last year and provided a dividend last year just before filing for dissolution. Since this is dividend form a foreign company, I believe the dividend will be taxable under other sources.

However, now, the shares in my demat account are showing as AABAESC instead of AABA, and their value is showing as 0.  Can I claim long term capital loss for the shares of AABA, or can I subtract the acquisition cost of these shares from the dividend income while filing the returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with CA. There have been quite a few changes in capital gains laws of shares, generally you can offset the capital loss with capital gains in same category.

So you may not be able to offset the loss against dividend income